# NiFi Processor JUnit Test with ControllerService

Tags: java, junit, apache-nifi

I am developing a NiFi processor and want to test it with JUnit, but one of the properties of Processor is a ControllerService, which is DBCPConnectionPool, but I don't know how to add this service to the JUnit Test?

I try to new DBCPConnectionPool(), but there no object named like that, although I have added all dependencies to my pom file, like the followings:

```
    <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
             <artifactId>nifi-dbcp-service-api</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
             <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
             <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
             <type>nar</type>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
             <artifactId>nifi-dbcp-service-api</artifactId>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-mock</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-processor-utils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-dbcp-service-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

runner.addControllerService(...);
```

Please give some recommendation about how to write this unit test, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you included the `nifi-dbcp-service-api` module twice, but one of those should be `nifi-dbcp-service`, which contains the implementation classes.

Then look at [`DBCPServiceTest`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-dbcp-service-bundle/nifi-dbcp-service/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/dbcp/DBCPServiceTest.java#L67) for examples of how to use the `DBCPConnectionPool` in a unit test.

Comment: It is really valuable.